# MATLAB: Unit step function

Tags: matlab, function

For some reason when I try to create a simple unit step function I just receive a straight line. I am pretty sure this is correct, but my graph tells me otherwise. Is there something I am doing wrong?

```
function mone=myOne(t)

[n,~] = size(t);

mone=zeros(n,1);

for i=1:n,

    if (t(i)>0), 

        mone(i) =  1;

    end
end
```

in the command window I type,

```
t = [-5:0.01:5]

plot(t, myOne(t))
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is your line:

```
[n,~] = size(t);
```

You only query the first dimension of `t`, which is `1` following

```
t = [-5:0.01:5]
size(t)

ans =

       1        1001
```

You can either transpose `t`

```
t = [-5:0.01:5].';
size(t)

ans =

        1001           1
```

or you `length` instead of `size`.

```
n = length(t);
```

Finally, a solution without the loop as proposed by @Dan is much faster.

Comment: Or call `t = t(:)` upfront to force it to be a column vector

Answer (score 2):

I can't see anything wrong with the logic behind your function but your implementation is very long winded. In Matlab you can just do this:

```
function mone=myOne(t)
    mone = t > 0;
end
```

or if you want to get a matrix of numbers and not logicals returned try

```
function mone=myOne(t)
    mone = (t > 0)*1;  %// Or if you prefer to cast explicitly:
                       %// double(t>0)
end
```

Also to add a shift parameter with default set to zero:

```
function mone=myOne(t, T)

    if nargin < 2
        T = 0;
    end

    mone = (t > T)*1;

end
```

usage:

```
t = [-5:0.01:5]
plot(t, myOne(t))
plot(t, myOne(t,3))
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to multiply by 0? Also, I believe that explicit casting to double is a lot clearer.

Comment: @Jonas oops, no either add 0 or multiply by 1 obviously. I've added the explicit option in the comments, it probably is clearer

Comment: I guess the `nargin > 1` should be `nargin < 2`.